# Is $readmem synthesizable in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, synthesis

I am trying to implement a microcontroller on an FPGA, and I need to give it a ROM for its program. If I use $readmemb, will that be correctly synthesized to a ROM? If not, what is the standard way to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It depends on the synthesis tool whether or not `$readmemb` is synthesizable.

Altera's [Recommended HDL Coding Styles](http://www.altera.com/literature/hb/qts/qts_qii51007.pdf) guide includes example 10-31 (page 10-38), which demonstrates a ROM inferred from `$readmemb` (reproduced below):

```
module dual_port_rom (
   input [(addr_width-1):0] addr_a, addr_b,
   input clk, 
   output reg [(data_width-1):0] q_a, q_b
);
   parameter data_width = 8;
   parameter addr_width = 8;
   reg [data_width-1:0] rom[2**addr_width-1:0];
   initial // Read the memory contents in the file
           // dual_port_rom_init.txt. 
   begin
      $readmemb("dual_port_rom_init.txt", rom);
   end
   always @ (posedge clk)
   begin
      q_a <= rom[addr_a];
      q_b <= rom[addr_b];
   end
endmodule
```

Similarly, Xilinx's [XST User Guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx12_4/xst.pdf) states that:

> The `$readmemb` and `$readmemh` system
>   tasks can be used to initialize block
>   memories. For more information, see:
>
> Initializing RAM From an External File
>   Coding Examples
>
> Use `$readmemb` for
>   binary and `$readmemh` for hexadecimal
>   representation. To avoid the possible
>   difference between XST and simulator
>   behavior, Xilinx® recommends that you
>   use index parameters in these system
>   tasks. See the following coding
>   example.
>
> `$readmemb("rams_20c.data",ram, 0, 7);`